# Is there such thing as a generic dependency resolution library for python?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, dependencies, dependency-management

I'm looking for something that might let me define some kind of 'fact', and 'dependencies' between facts, and define functions which will attempt to resolve these dependencies.

Sort of like the way that a package manager resolves dependencies between packages, but a library that abstracts that dependency resolution process.

As in I'd like to be able to declare that I'd like fact A to be true, and that fact A also requires fact B to be true, and given some set of inputs that would allow it to determine whether A and B are true, this system would do whatever it takes to make both A and B true.

Comment: Not aware of anything that satisfies this specific case, but it sounds like your problem domain has an underlying graph structure (with facts being the nodes, and dependencies being edges). It may be worth taking a look at [python-graph](https://code.google.com/p/python-graph/) which allows you to build graphs and also provides a number of algorithms for working with graphs.

Comment: You might have better luck asking on [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), and a keyword that might assist your search is topological sorting.

Comment: @kalhartt SR mod here. Please make sure to add a link to our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/46) - we require much more information than an average question here contains. Thanks!

Comment: @Undo I'll remember that in the future, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been a very long time since this question was asked but I had exactly the same question and I could not find anything useful on Google...

**TL;DR:** Based on [this](http://www.electricmonk.nl/docs/dependency_resolving_algorithm/dependency_resolving_algorithm.html) post I started working on a multi-version dependency resolving algorithm which you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/urban-1/ae42dd6a7c5c0deef8bc9a6906d2bcb0). I cannot guarantee it is correct but *seems* complete. It was more of an experiment but it runs successfully with a controlled data-set and produces a result with random data.

Now, what I have learned from this process is that is fairly easy to implement a simple dependency resolution algorithm that handles most of the cases on known data and works on a "flat" graph. However, this gets a lot more complex if one takes into consideration multiple versions, range based dependencies (ie `version > 2.0 and !2.2`) as opposed to absolute ones, multiple correct solutions, incomplete or incorrect data.

The most noticeable problem, in complex cases, is Circular Dependencies (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)). These definitely exists on software/package managers. I have attempted to solve it with a round-based approach which will either lead to a solution, a failure or a (detected) loop after a number of attempts.

Finally, I tried to generalize the problem and create a reusable library. You will notice thought that my main logic (`_resolve()`) is a lot more straight forward than `satisfy_criteria()` which is problem/area specific function of dependecy acceptance. Also, the circular dependency "resolution" is completely based on package management/versioning and most probably is not applicable to any other case/area.

The above lead me to believe that despite the fact that most of the solutions will involve graphs, at one stage or another, there cannot be a high-level generic solution to the dependency resolution problem.

My next step (given time) would be to start reading `apt-get`, `rpm` or `aptitude` sources and see how other people solved this problem...